# What do these arrows in Maven RequireUpperBoundDeps mean?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

```
 Failed while enforcing RequireUpperBoundDeps. The error(s) are [
 Require upper bound dependencies error for io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.8.37, should be 4.8.37,  paths to dependency are:
 +-com.foo.bar:foobar:foorbar-SNAPSHOT
   +-io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2:2.1.10
     +-io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.8.37 (managed) <--- 4.8.95
 and
 +-com.foo.bar:foobar:foorbar-SNAPSHOT
   +-io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-integration:2.1.10
     +-io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.8.37 (managed) <--- 4.8.95
 and
 +-com.foo.bar:foobar:foorbar-SNAPSHOT
   +-com.bar.foo:barfoo:barfoo-SNAPSHOT
     +-org.javers:javers-core:5.6.1
       +-io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.8.37 (managed) <--- 4.4.12
```

How would I resolve this issue?
what do the `<--- 4.8.95` and `<--- 4.4.12` mean?
Also `for io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.8.37, should be 4.8.37` looks like it's correct?

The official maven documentation doesn't address these https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireUpperBoundDeps.html

I did `mvn dependency:tree` and all I got was

```
[INFO] +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2:jar:2.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.37:compile
```

Nothing else bringing `io.github.classgraph:classgraph` in to my project.